# 1-Hour Timeout on SSAS 2014 + ADOMD.Net - but no Timeouts Set to an Hour

Tags: ado.net, ssas, adomd.net

I've run into a mystifying XMLA timeout error when running an ADOMD.Net command from a .Net application. The Visual Basic routine iterates over a list of mining models residing on a SQL Server Analysis Services 2014 instance and performs a cross-validation test on each one. Whenever the time elapsed on the cross-validation test reaches the 60 minute mark, the XML for Analysis parser throws an error, saying that the request timed out. For any routine operations taking less than one hour, I can use the same ADOMD.Net connections with the same server and application without any hitches. The culprit in such cases is often the ExternalCommandTimeout setting on the server, which defaults to 3600 seconds, i.e one hour. In this case, however, all of the following timeout properties on the server are set to zero: CommitTimeout, ExternalCommandTimeout, ExternalConnectionTimeout, ForceCommitTimeout,  IdleConnectionTimeout, IdleOrphanSessionTimeout, MaxIdleSessionTimeout and ServerTimeout.
There are only three other timeout properties available, none of which is set to one hour: MinldleSessionTimeout (currently at 2700), DatabaseConnectionPoolConnectTimeout (now at 60 seconds) and DatabaseConnectionPoolTimeout (at 120000). The MSDN documentation lists another three timeout properties that aren't visible with the Advanced Properties checked in SQL Server Management Studio 2017: 
AdminTimeout, DefaultLockTimeoutMS and DatabaseConnectionPoolGeneralTimeout. The first two default to no timeout and the third defaults to one minute. MSDN also mentions a few "forbidden" timeout properties, like SocketOptions\ LingerTimeout, InitialConnectTimeout, ServerReceiveTimeout, ServerSendTimeout, which all carry the warning, "An advanced property that you should not change, except under the guidance of Microsoft support." I do not see any means of setting these through the SSMS 2017 GUI though.

Since I've literally run out of timeout settings to try, I'm stumped as to how to correct this behavior and allow my .Net app to wait on those cross-validations through ADOMD. Long ago I was able to solve a few arcane SSAS timeout issues by appending certain property settings to the connection strings, such as "Connect Timeout=0;CommitTimeout=0;Timeout=0" and so on. Nevertheless, attempting to assign an ExternalCommandTimeout value through the connection string in this manner results in the XMLA error
"The ExternalCommandTimeout property was not recognized." I have not tested each and every one of the SSAS server timeouts in this manner, but this exception signifies that ADOMD.Net connection strings can only accept a subset of the timeout properties.

Am I missing a timeout setting somewhere? Does anyone have any ideas on what else could cause this kind of esoteric error? Thanks in advance. I've put this issue on the back burner about as long as I can and really need to get it fixed now. I wonder if perhaps ADOMD.Net has its own separate timeout settings, perhaps going by different names, but I can't find any documentation to that effect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked down the cause of this error: buried deep in the VB.Net code on the front end was a line that set the CommandTimeout property of the ADOMD.Net Command object to 3600 seconds. This overrode the connection string settings mentioned above, as well as all of the server-level settings. The problem was masked by the fact that cross-validation retrieval operations were also timing out in the Visual Studio 2017 GUI. That occurred because the VS instance was only recently installed and the Connection and Query Timeouts hadn't yet been set to 0 under Options menu/Business Intelligence Designers/Analysis Services Designs/General.